# V8 grows virtual memory and then generates fatal error

Tags: v8

I'm calling following code after running each script:

```
unsigned nCycleCount = 0;
while(!v8::V8::IdleNotification()) { ++nCycleCount; }
```

to force garbage collection.

As result virtual memory amount rapidly grows and the V8 just indicates fatal error, it cannot allocated more virtual memory.
What is the reason? Is there any fix or workaround? Does anyone know?
Build Platform: Win32/x86
Compiler: VS2005 + SP1 + ATL Security Pack + MFC Security pack

Comment: Can you provide more information? For example, are you reusing the same V8 isolate and context for each script run? Are you sure your scripts aren't creating objects and leaving them dangling from the global object? Etc.

Comment: Yes,I'm reusing same isolate and same context for each script run. Also,I'm having multiple isolates which are used in the multiple threads. Once isolate created, it may be used one time in one thread, another time in the another thread, however there's no situation that two threads attempt to use the same isolate simultaneously.Yes,some scripts that I'm running do create objects, but they are function-bound and do not attach them to the global.Also I'm passing some native objects wrapped into V8 objects to script as parameters.But these wrappers are cleaned up once script execution completed.

Comment: How does your application manage isolate lifetime? Is it possible that it gets to a point where it's using several dozen active isolates? One thing that wasn't obvious to me is that each isolate reserves a 32MB block of address space, so even with nothing else going on in your application, a 32-bit process will run out of address space at 64 isolates.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much. Your last comment probably explains what is going on, because I was trying to create over 80 isolates, and it was failing somewhere in the middle. But I still have a question - when this address space is getting allocated? When I comment out call to IdleNotificartion() everything goes fine. 80 isolates are created. So I think it is allocated during the IdleNotification(). Please explain in more details this, if possible.

Comment: It looks like V8 reserves the large block of address space when an isolate's heap is initialized. In my tests, this happens the first time the isolate is locked, but there may be other ways to trigger it as well. The bottom line is that you may be able to create more than 64 isolates, but attempting to use that many in any capacity will result in virtual address space exhaustion.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'm not a big specialist in the V8 internals, although recent weeks I've learned a bit more, but what you say is exactly matches to the Call Stack figures which I can see in the Visual Studio debugger when V8 raises fatal error about out of memory. It really happens when the new isolate is locked for a first time and its heap is getting initialized.

Comment: But I also wonder, whether this memory amount is controllable, i.e. can we call something in V8 API to change this amount from 32MB to someting less, and how to determine the reasonable amount of VM for the particular usage case? The point is that I'm not running very bug amd complex scripts, so probably some less VM amount will fit good for my purposes.

Comment: It doesn't look like it's configurable. V8 uses a simple calculation based on the size of a pointer. In a 32-bit process that calculation yields 16MB, but V8 reserves 32MB in an attempt to reserve 16MB at a 16MB boundary. Once it has an aligned address it actually shrinks the reservation back to 16MB. So it's not as bad as 32MB per isolate, but much worse than 16MB with default (64KB) alignment. No idea why it does any of this. Unfortunately all I can recommend is that you switch to a 64-bit process.

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually, I also must think of reducing number of V8 isolates to the some preallocated constant pool and sharing them between internal tasks of my application.